# Python find index of maximum in a partially updated array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, max

**Question**: How can I find the index of the (global) maximum in a real-valued, 1D array, that is partially updated during loop iterations at a (comparatively) small number of known, but varying, indices *most efficiently* in Python? In particular, how can I keep the computation time per iteration constant if the size of the 1D array increases whereas the number of updated values remains bounded?

**Context:** I am implementing the CLEAN deconvolution algorithm ([Högbom, 1974](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/1974A%26AS...15..417H/ADS_PDF); [Roberts+, 1987](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/1987AJ.....93..968R/ADS_PDF)) in an efficient variant ([Clark, 1980](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/1980A%26A....89..377C/ADS_PDF)) to remove spectral side lobes (aliases) in power spectra as a function of frequency and azimuthal order m. The algorithm uses two nested loops, the major (outer) and minor (inner) cycles. During the minor iterations, I need to find the index `ind_sel_max` of the maximum of a 1D power spectral density (PSD) array `psd_check_temp` (the absolute-squared of a complex-valued Fourier transform array `fu_check_temp`), which is partially updated between the minor iterations at the indices `ind_within_beam`. The indices `ind_within_beam` may vary between the minor iterations both in values and number of elements, but have a maximum number of elements that becomes small compared to `len(psd_check_temp)`, given sufficiently many iterations. Exemplarily, `len(ind_check_temp)` could be ~2500 at maximum and `len(psd_check_temp)` could grow up to >~300000 at maximum. `len(psd_check_temp)` changes only between major, but not between minor iterations. During a given iteration, a priori I do not know how exactly the values of `psd_check_temp` will change (often but not always they will decrease), but it may be computed during the next iteration. However, `ind_sel_max` is always included in `ind_with_beam` and `psd_check_temp[ind_sel_max]` will be updated during the iterations.

**Loop structure:**

```
i_major = 0
while continue_major_loop:
    i_minor = 0
    # code of outer loop
    ...
    while continue_minor_loop:
        # code of inner loop
        ...
        i_minor += 1
    # code of outer loop
    ...
    i_major += 1
```

**Code example 1 (inside inner loop, slow):**

```
        # compute the PSD
        if i_minor == 0:
            psd_check_temp = np.real(fu_check_temp)**2 + np.imag(fu_check_temp)**2
        else:
            psd_check_temp[ind_within_beam] = np.real(fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam])**2 + np.imag(fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam])**2
        # find the index of the maximum PSD
        ind_sel_max = np.argmax(psd_check_temp)
        ...
        ind_within_beam = ...
        fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam] -= ...
        ...
```

**Issue 1:** Finding the index of the maximum via `np.argmax()` in each iteration (see code above) will use increasingly more computation time as `len(psd_check_temp)` gets larger during each major iteration, and thus becomes quite slow after sufficiently many iterations.

**Question:** Since only a small part of the PSD array is updated during the iterations, intuitively I would guess there should be a way to keep the computation time per iteration bounded to the number of elements that are updated (which itself is bounded as written above exemplarily to ~2500), instead of checking the entire array `psd_check_temp` for the maximum. How can I best accomplish this?

My idea was to sort `psd_check_temp` once during the first minor iteration, and in each iteration sort the updated PSD values only, keep the non-updated PSD values, find the indices to insert the sorted updated PSD values into the sorted non-updated PSD values via `np.searchsorted()` and insert the sorted updated PSD values via `np.insert()`. Since `psd_check_temp` will remain sorted, the index of the maximum PSD is the last one. However, I need to also process `fu_check_temp` and a couple of 1D (`inu_check_temp`, `im_check_temp`) and 2D (`ind_2d`) index arrays accordingly.

**Code example 2 (even slower):**

```
...
# create a 2D index array, filled with index -1 (marking invalid points)
ind_2d = np.full((nnu_use,nm), fill_value=-1, dtype=int)
...
while continue_major_loop:
    ...       
    # get a 1D array of indices corresponding to the 1D frequency and m index arrays
    ind_1d = np.arange(len(inu_check_temp))
    # fill the index array with the indices corresponding to the 1D frequency and m index arrays
    ind_2d[inu_check_temp, im_check_temp] = ind_1d
    ...
    while continue_minor_loop:
        if i_minor == 0:
            psd_check_temp = np.real(fu_check_temp)**2 + np.imag(fu_check_temp)**2
            # find the indices that sort the PSD array and sort the PSD and Fourier transform arrays as well
            # as the frequency and m index arrays accordingly
            ind_sort_temp = np.argsort(psd_check_temp)
            psd_check_temp = psd_check_temp[ind_sort_temp]
            fu_check_temp = fu_check_temp[ind_sort_temp]
            inu_check_temp = inu_check_temp[ind_sort_temp]
            im_check_temp = im_check_temp[ind_sort_temp]
            # also update the 2D index array accordingly
            ind_2d[inu_check_temp, im_check_temp] = ind_1d
        else:
            psd_updated_temp = np.real(fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam])**2 + np.imag(fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam])**2
            # (1) get the indices to sort the PSD of the updated Fourier transform
            ind_sort_temp = np.argsort(psd_updated_temp)
            # (2) sort the PSD, Fourier transform, and frequency and m index arrays accordingly
            psd_updated_temp = psd_updated_temp[ind_sort_temp]
            fu_updated_temp = fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam][ind_sort_temp]
            inu_updated_temp = inu_check_temp[ind_within_beam][ind_sort_temp]
            im_updated_temp = im_check_temp[ind_within_beam][ind_sort_temp]
            # (3) get the 1D indices of the array elements that have not been updated; np.setdiff1d() only returns
            # unique elements, but that is ok for index arrays where there are no duplicates; also it returns
            # the indices in order
            ind_complement_temp = np.setdiff1d(ind_1d, ind_1d[ind_within_beam], assume_unique=True)
            # (4) keep only the values that were not updated
            psd_cut_temp = psd_check_temp[ind_complement_temp]
            fu_cut_temp = fu_check_temp[ind_complement_temp]
            inu_cut_temp = inu_check_temp[ind_complement_temp]
            im_cut_temp = im_check_temp[ind_complement_temp]
            # (5) find the indices where to insert the updated values in the sorted arrays
            ind_insert_temp = np.searchsorted(psd_cut_temp, psd_updated_temp)
            # (6) insert the updated values in the sorted arrays
            psd_check_temp = np.insert(psd_cut_temp,ind_insert_temp,psd_updated_temp)
            fu_check_temp = np.insert(fu_cut_temp,ind_insert_temp,fu_updated_temp)
            inu_check_temp = np.insert(inu_cut_temp,ind_insert_temp,inu_updated_temp)
            im_check_temp = np.insert(im_cut_temp,ind_insert_temp,im_updated_temp)
            # (7) also update the 2D index array accordingly
            ind_2d[inu_check_temp, im_check_temp] = ind_1d
        # the index of the maximum corresponds to the last array element, since the array is sorted
        ind_sel_max = len(psd_check_temp) - 1
        ...
        ind_within_beam = ...
        fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam] -= ...
        ...
```

**Issue 2:** This implementation is even slower than the one in code example 1. For 10000 iterations, the algorithm takes ~0.2 seconds for code example 1 and 12 seconds for code example 2, and I need 10^6 or more iterations. The computation times for the steps `np.insert()` (6), `np.setdiff1d()` (3), `ind_2d` update (7), keeping the non-updated values (4), `np.searchsorted()` (5), `np.argsort(psd_check_temp)`(1) and sorting the updated values (2), are 4.5, 2.7, 2.0, 1.2, 0.6, 0.5 and 0.2 seconds, respectively. Also this implementation requests memory a lot of times.

**Any advice/help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Can you show the code which modifies the `psd_check_temp` array in size? There is `psd_check_temp[ind_within_beam] = ...` but that won't change the size of the array, so I'm wondering why you need to deal with that size changing issue at all?

Comment: @a_guest: `psd_check_temp` increases in size because `fu_check_temp` does. `fu_check_temp` is obtained in the major loop via `fu_check_temp = fu_resid[:nnu_use][mask_check_temp]`. `mask_check_temp` is a boolean mask of elements whose PSD is larger than some PSD threshold (which changes within each major iteration), which I use to index a 2D array `fu_resid`. As the PSD threshold changes (it will generally become smaller), the number of `True` elements in `mask_check_temp` increases and so does the size of the 1D array `fu_check_temp` resulting from the boolean mask indexing.

Comment: @bproxauf Can't you just save your maximum and it's index and every time you update the array you also update the saved maximum? It would have the advantage that you only have to look at everything once since you can compare incoming entries with the saved maximum.

Comment: @user2640045: During a given iteration, the found maximum, i.e. `psd_check_temp[ind_sel_max]` will be changed, as `ind_sel_max` is always included in `ind_with_beam` (I edited the question to clarify this). When we compare the updated values with a previously saved/stored maximum and the updated values are smaller (they will typically be), we still do not know whether the new maximum of `psd_check_temp` is inside `ind_with_beam` or among the non-updated values.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `psd_check_temp` arrays seems to remain of constant size during the minor loop iterations, you can compute its maximum only over the updates indices:

```py
        # compute the PSD
        if i_minor == 0:
            psd_check_temp = np.real(fu_check_temp)**2 + np.imag(fu_check_temp)**2
            ind_sel_max = np.argmax(psd_check_temp)
        else:
            psd_check_temp[ind_within_beam] = np.real(fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam])**2 + np.imag(fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam])**2
            ind_sel_max_candidate = ind_within_beam[np.argmax(psd_check_temp[ind_within_beam])]
            if psd_check_temp[ind_sel_max_candidate] > psd_check_temp[ind_sel_max]:
                ind_sel_max = ind_sel_max_candidate
        ...
        ind_within_beam = ...
        fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam] -= ...
        ...
```

Comment: During the minor iterations, `ind_within_beam` always contains the index of the maximum (apart from the other indices). Thus when `fu_check_temp[ind_within_beam]` is altered, the PSD at the maximum is altered. If the maximum of `psd_check_temp[ind_within_beam]` is smaller than the previous maximum (and it likely will be), we don't know whether the maximum of `psd_check_temp` is among `psd_check_temp[ind_within_beam]` or among the non-updated values.

Comment: I slightly clarified some of these points in the context paragraph.